# Limiting an Array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

This is my code below, I get an java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException & I can't fix it? I am supposed to STOP the error from coming up because I have over 100 names in the file!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayPractice1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        String[] names = new String[100];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
        int index = 0;

        while (scan.hasNext()){
            names[index]=(scan.nextLine());
            index++;
        }     
        for(int i = 0; i <index -1; i++){
            System.out.println(names[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where's the `ArrayList`?

Comment: Is it possible, that the names.txt file contains more than 100 rows?

Comment: You can save a code line: names[index++]=(scan.nextLine());

Comment: what are the contents of `names.txt`?

Comment: Are you sure that your file has 100 lines. You can use i < names.length in you for loop

Comment: also, are you aware your `i <index -1` eliminates the last file line from printing?

Answer (score 2):

youre not working with an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of Strings, you're working with a plain array of Strings.
seems like youre getting more than 100 items from `scan.hasNext()` and so you eventually try to access `names[100]` and get the exception you describe 
instead, you could use this:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then

```
while (scan.hasNext()){
   names.add(scan.nextLine());
}
```

and you wont have to worry about knowing the exact size beforehand

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the input is not known at compile time, consider using an [**`ArrayList`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array.

Just add the elements to the `ArrayList` using [`names.add(scan.nextLine())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29):

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scan.hasNext()) {
      names.add(scan.nextLine())
}
```

Comment: My apologies! I forgot it was a normal array!

Answer (score 0):

You are giving 100 as the size of array.If your file have more than 100 lines, definitely it will throw exception

Answer (score 0):

change the condition in your while loop to

`while (scan.hasNext() && index < 100)`

this will stop the read loop after you fill up the array

Answer (score 0):

Why not making it independent from any upper limit? Use an *ArrayList*:

```
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));

    while (scan.hasNext()){
        names.add(scan.nextLine());
    }     
    for(String name : names){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```